# .parseBoolean turns out "false" with the String being "true"?

Tags: java, filereader, java-io

So I was trying to make a program that reads the content of a .txt file and then stores it as a boolean

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String textRead = "";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("test.txt");
        char[] Array = new char[100];
        fileReader.read(Array);
        
        for(int i = 0; i<Array.length; i++) 
        {
            //if I were to print textRead it would print true
            textRead = textRead + Array[i];
        }
        //The .txt file contains only "true" and nothing else
        boolean test = Boolean.parseBoolean(textRead);
        //This prints out false for some reason
        System.out.print(test);
        
        fileReader.close();

    }

}
```

But when I run this it prints out the value "false" even though the .txt that was supposed to be read only contained "true".

I tried looking for a solution but didn't get very far as I am still pretty new to java and coding in general, can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: `textRead = textRead.trim();` Your string will be full of nulls from your redundant array. You'd be better off reading lines

Comment: Alright thanks. I didn't know about the array leaving nulls in the string.

Comment: Bear in mind too that parsing booleans is error prone. e.g. `System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean("This is garbage"));` will return `false`. Even though it's 'true' ;)

Comment: Damn looks like we got a comedian here

Comment: Yes but it's a serious joke

Answer (score 1):

This is, in fact the content of your `String` without trimming:

```
00000000: 7472 7565 0a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  true............
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000                                ....
```

Unlike languages like C/C++, Java `String`s *can* contain null characters. So you need `textRead = textRead.trim();` after reading, but as I said, it would be better to read lines. Having said that, however you read it, it would be wise to call `trim()` ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the *char* array is created it will initially contain null character values.

```java
char[] Array = new char[100];
```

So, when you are looping though *Array*, *textRead* will have null *char* values appended to it.

```java
textRead = textRead + Array[i];
```

You can avoid this by adding a check within the *for-loop*.

```java
for(int i = 0; i<Array.length; i++)
{
    if (Array[i] == '\u0000') break;

    //if I were to print textRead it would print true
    textRead = textRead + Array[i];
}
```

Alternately, you can utilize the *[String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D))* constructor method, or the *[String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char%5B%5D))* method, to construct the string.
Subsequently, use the *[String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim())* method to remove any leading and trailing white-space characters—which includes the null character.

```java
textRead = new String(Array).trim();
```

```java
textRead = String.valueOf(Array).trim();
```

It's worth noting, you can utilize the *[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html)* class, which has a *[readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())* method.

```java
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
textRead = fileReader.readLine();
fileReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) { return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(s); }`

Hope that explains your issue.
Also the unused elements in your char array are treated as nulls

Answer (score 0):

You've already been explained (quite nicely) the problem with arbitrarily declaring an array to hold values where you possibly have no idea how many elements you may need to read the entire file of boolean values so I won't do that again here. I will suggest however, that you don't use an array at all but instead, use a [List Interface](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_list_interface.htm) or an [ArrayList](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-an-arraylist-in-java) to hold file line results which can grow *dynamically* and wont possibly end up being full of **null** or **empty** elements (if you don't want it to).

Below is an example of how a List Interface can be used. Be sure to read the comments in code.

It should be noted that, *in this use case*, the file lines are trimmed of white-spacing etc as the file lines are read. You will also note that the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method is used with a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) string to validate the fact that a read file line contains either "true" or "false". Below is a brief explanation of the regex used:

- `(?i)` Ignore letter case;
- `true` The file line contains only "true";
- `|` OR
- `false` The file line contains only "false";

Again...read the comments in code:

```
// List Interface to hold true/false file line results:
List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
/* `Try With Resources` used here to auto-close() the reader
   and free resources when done.        */
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        line = reader.nextLine().trim();
        /* Any file line that contains anything other than
           true or false is ignored, including blank lines. */
        // Is the line true or false (not letter case sensitive):
        if (line.matches("(?i)true|false")) {
            // Convert line to boolean and add to List:
            list.add(Boolean.valueOf(line));
        }
    }

    // Convert list to an array if you like (after the reading):
    // Boolean[] array = list.toArray(new Boolean[0]);
        
    // Display List:
    for (Boolean bool : list) {
        System.out.println(bool);
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```